# Using AWK to mail merge two files producing reformated third file

Tags: awk, merge

This isn't so much a question. This is my first post as well. I'm not a newbie but I'm also only at a beginner level to awk.

Recently I had needed to generate some .xml config files from two sets of data that's not stored initially as xml.

I searched a lot for AWK help but I realize that 99% of provided scripts uses advanced AWK techniques which makes it difficult for beginners to figure out. This I believe will both drive away interest and drive up learning curves.

EG.
awk '{/ERROR/}' < /var/log/messages

Not very easy for a person who doesn't do much awk scripts to know what is going on there, yet it does a bunch.

So here I'm going to provide a newbie take on accomplishing such task. In return

I would like for suggestions for

1. a more optimized newbie version.
2. an optimized Advanced version with proper explanation that will assist with transitioning.

$./test1.awk Samfig2.cfg user1.tsv
$ls  cfg*
cfg2ZR6ZS29XXOF.xml  cfg42IXEIGOQ0FG.xml  cfg759YUZKTS368.xml  cfgNTQALYCPLE06.xml  cfgYDMWJVLO6YWS.xml

**test1.awk**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { 
        configfile=ARGV[1]
        Userfile=ARGV[2]
      
        if (ARGV[2] == "") {
                        print "ERROR: Need two files Usage "ENVIRON["_"]" Config.cfg Users.tsv" >"/dev/stderr"
                        exit }
       ARGV[1] = ""   # We want to control the manipulation of files
       ARGV[2] = ""
        FS = "=" ;  # this is being done dynamically, no need here (oh yes setting here cause almost 90% execution reduction)
        getline Header < Userfile;  # advance the Header line and get the headers
         gsub("\r","",Header);  # My production version doesnt need this but the sample data seem to include \r on the end field
        HeaderN=split(Header,Headarray,"\t");

# Expand begin block to include {} below to prevent pause for input       }
#{   

while ((getline User < Userfile) >0 )  # Read row from field into variable User do all the blocks below based on the number of records in Userfile.
   { 
    gsub("\r","",User); # My production version doesnt need this but the sample data seem to include \r on the end field
    n=split(User,Detailsarray,"\t");           # split row stored in User into array called Detailsarray n stores the total number of elements with FS =\t
    filetostore=("cfg" Detailsarray[HeaderN] ".xml"); # Were are storing each file based on Last Header value in the user file
    Recordtmp=""                               #To reduce file IO will append to string then output later. 
    Recordtmp ="<?xml version=\42""1.0\42 encoding=\42utf-8\42?>";   #\42 is the double quote ". Result is  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
                                                                #without the "" set you would get <?xml version=.0" encoding="utf-8"?> as it would interpret as \421 
    Recordtmp = Recordtmp "\n<users_provision version=\42""1\42>";
    Recordtmp = Recordtmp "\n<config version=\42""1\42>"; 
    
    for(i=1; i<=HeaderN; i++)  # We could also use n instead of HeaderN but just incase I'm maintaining base on the initial header
        Recordtmp = Recordtmp  "\n    <" Headarray[i] ">" Detailsarray[i] "</" Headarray[i] ">"; 
                      
    while ((getline < configfile) >0 )
        {    
            Recordtmp = Recordtmp  "\n    <" $1 ">" $2 "</" $1 ">";
         }
    Recordtmp = Recordtmp  "\n</config>"; 
    Recordtmp = Recordtmp  "\n</users_provision>\n";
    
    close(configfile);
   
    print (Recordtmp)> filetostore;
    close(filetostore);     

   }
#}

# END {  # Had to expand begin block to avoid pause issue
      close(Userfile);
     }
```

**Samfig.cfg**

```
URL=msn.com
Dealer=RealtorSales
SQRFT=3600
Taxes=6000
Asking=1,800,000
Built=July/2019
Listed=07/12/2109
MSRP=2,000,000
Kitchen=5
Baths=2.5
floors=3
Rooms=5
```

**user1.tsv**

```
Name    StreeNum    StreetName  City    State   ZIP IDcard
Ashanti Simmons 138 Jockey Hollow Avenue    Phillipsburg    NJ  08865   2ZR6ZS29XXOF
Bobby Marshall  7985 E.     Beech Road  Flemington  NJ  08822   YDMWJVLO6YWS
Marianna Quinn  8950    Main St.    Moses Lake  WA  98837   42IXEIGOQ0FG
Jaslyn Fuentes  9581    Lafayette Dr.   Hummelstown PA  17036   NTQALYCPLE06
Cory Jordan 26  Randall Mill Street Bay City    MI  48706   759YUZKTS368
```

**Contents of cfg2ZR6ZS29XXOF.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users_provision version="1">
<config version="1">
    <Name>Ashanti Simmons</Name>
    <StreeNum>138</StreeNum>
    <StreetName>Jockey Hollow Avenue</StreetName>
    <City>Phillipsburg</City>
    <State>NJ</State>
    <ZIP>08865</ZIP>
    <IDcard>2ZR6ZS29XXOF</IDcard>
    <URL>msn.com</URL>
    <Dealer>RealtorSales</Dealer>
    <SQRFT>3600</SQRFT>
    <Taxes>6000</Taxes>
    <Asking>1,800,000</Asking>
    <Built>July/2019</Built>
    <Listed>07/12/2109</Listed>
    <MSRP>2,000,000</MSRP>
    <Kitchen>5</Kitchen>
    <Baths>2.5</Baths>
    <floors>3</floors>
    <Rooms>5</Rooms>
</config>
</users_provision>
```

For improvements these could be done.

1. Read the FS/split values into variables from command line.
2. Only replace default value that exist in config file if its not null in data file.

Comment: (Hmm, I can't get the formatting for the intitial "call the script" code to clean up, i.e. `$./test1.awk` etc.) Otherwise you seem to have a good understanding of how `awk` works. I don't understand  your comment `# Expand begin block to include {} below to prevent pause for input`. Sometimes the best solution is to have all processing inside of `BEGIN{}` or `END{}`. If you output XML passes `xmllint` verification , declare victory! Getting more advanced features XML from `awk` is a real "opportunity for learning", See maybe `xmlawk` (Will try and find a link). Good luck.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gawkextlib/  may help (at the expense of having a still steeper learning curve ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: Because i unset the ARGV values awk paused the script waiting for user input when it was written in the middle block.  Hence the commenting.

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
$ awk 'function bt(t)    {return "<"t">"}
       function et(t)    {return bt("/"t)}
       function tag(t,v) {return bt(t) v et(t)}
       function prolog() {return bt("?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?")}
       function start(t) {return bt(t " version=\"1\"")}

       NR==FNR {split($0,a,"="); ks[NR]=a[1]; vs[NR]=a[2]; nk=NR; next}
       FNR==1  {n=split($0,header); next}
               {file="cfg" $NF ".xml"
                print prolog() > file
                print start("users_provision") > file
                print start("config") > file
                for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "\t" tag(header[i],$i) > file
                for(i=1;i<=nk;i++) print "\t" tag(ks[i], vs[i]) > file
                print et("config") > file
                print et("user_provision") > file
                close(file)}' config FS='\t' user
```

with some helper function to simply the main body of the code.  No error checks or validations though.

produces

```
$ cat cfg2ZR6ZS29XXOF.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users_provision version="1">
<config version="1">
        <Name>Ashanti Simmons</Name>
        <StreeNum>138</StreeNum>
        <StreetName>Jockey Hollow Avenue</StreetName>
        <City>Phillipsburg</City>
        <State>NJ</State>
        <ZIP>08865</ZIP>
        <IDcard>2ZR6ZS29XXOF</IDcard>
        <URL>msn.com</URL>
        <Dealer>RealtorSales</Dealer>
        <SQRFT>3600</SQRFT>
        <Taxes>6000</Taxes>
        <Asking>1,800,000</Asking>
        <Built>July/2019</Built>
        <Listed>07/12/2109</Listed>
        <MSRP>2,000,000</MSRP>
        <Kitchen>5</Kitchen>
        <Baths>2.5</Baths>
        <floors>3</floors>
        <Rooms>5</Rooms>
</config>
</user_provision>
```

Unless you're working on massive sized files, I think optimization should be on easiness of maintenance.  Although most awk scripts are ephemeral, with proper structure and comments it can be useful for a long time.

Comment: This is a nicely optimized version. I didn't know about the possibility of procedural programming for awk. I don't see the substitution of the pesky \r on $0. I see you employed 2 arrays(keystring and valuestring) to allow for the post processing of the first input file.

For the benefit  of those passing by later I'd have preferred some commenting. Love it nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have missed the main point of awk which is that it reads the input file(s) for you and so you've written an awk script the way you'd write a C program with a bunch of while-read loops in the BEGIN section to manually do what awk does automatically. I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "\t"
    fmt = "   <%s>%s</%s>\n"
}
{ sub(/\r$/,"") }
NR == FNR {
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^=]+=/,"",val)
    comm = comm sprintf(fmt, tag, val, tag)
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        tags[i] = $i
    }
    next
}
{
    out = "cfg" $NF ".xml"

    print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"  > out
    print "<users_provision version=\"1\">"             > out
    print "<config version=\"1\">"                      > out

    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf fmt, tags[i], $i, tags[i]                > out
    }

    printf "%s", comm                                   > out

    print "</config>"                                   > out
    print "</users_provision>"                          > out

    close(out)
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk Samfig.cfg user1.tsv
```

.

```
$ head -50 cfg*.xml
==> cfg2ZR6ZS29XXOF.xml <==
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users_provision version="1">
<config version="1">
   <Name>Ashanti Simmons</Name>
   <StreeNum>138</StreeNum>
   <StreetName>Jockey Hollow Avenue</StreetName>
   <City>Phillipsburg</City>
   <State>NJ</State>
   <ZIP>08865</ZIP>
   <IDcard>2ZR6ZS29XXOF</IDcard>
   <URL>msn.com</URL>
   <Dealer>RealtorSales</Dealer>
   <SQRFT>3600</SQRFT>
   <Taxes>6000</Taxes>
   <Asking>1,800,000</Asking>
   <Built>July/2019</Built>
   <Listed>07/12/2109</Listed>
   <MSRP>2,000,000</MSRP>
   <Kitchen>5</Kitchen>
   <Baths>2.5</Baths>
   <floors>3</floors>
   <Rooms>5</Rooms>
</config>
</users_provision>

==> cfg42IXEIGOQ0FG.xml <==
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users_provision version="1">
<config version="1">
   <Name>Marianna Quinn</Name>
   <StreeNum>8950</StreeNum>
   <StreetName>Main St.</StreetName>
   <City>Moses Lake</City>
   <State>WA</State>
   <ZIP>98837</ZIP>
   <IDcard>42IXEIGOQ0FG</IDcard>
   <URL>msn.com</URL>
   <Dealer>RealtorSales</Dealer>
   <SQRFT>3600</SQRFT>
   <Taxes>6000</Taxes>
   <Asking>1,800,000</Asking>
   <Built>July/2019</Built>
   <Listed>07/12/2109</Listed>
   <MSRP>2,000,000</MSRP>
   <Kitchen>5</Kitchen>
   <Baths>2.5</Baths>
   <floors>3</floors>
   <Rooms>5</Rooms>
</config>
</users_provision>

==> cfg759YUZKTS368.xml <==
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users_provision version="1">
<config version="1">
   <Name>Cory Jordan</Name>
   <StreeNum>26</StreeNum>
   <StreetName>Randall Mill Street</StreetName>
   <City>Bay City</City>
   <State>MI</State>
   <ZIP>48706</ZIP>
   <IDcard>759YUZKTS368</IDcard>
   <URL>msn.com</URL>
   <Dealer>RealtorSales</Dealer>
   <SQRFT>3600</SQRFT>
   <Taxes>6000</Taxes>
   <Asking>1,800,000</Asking>
   <Built>July/2019</Built>
   <Listed>07/12/2109</Listed>
   <MSRP>2,000,000</MSRP>
   <Kitchen>5</Kitchen>
   <Baths>2.5</Baths>
   <floors>3</floors>
   <Rooms>5</Rooms>
</config>
</users_provision>

==> cfgNTQALYCPLE06.xml <==
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users_provision version="1">
<config version="1">
   <Name>Jaslyn Fuentes</Name>
   <StreeNum>9581</StreeNum>
   <StreetName>Lafayette Dr.</StreetName>
   <City>Hummelstown</City>
   <State>PA</State>
   <ZIP>17036</ZIP>
   <IDcard>NTQALYCPLE06</IDcard>
   <URL>msn.com</URL>
   <Dealer>RealtorSales</Dealer>
   <SQRFT>3600</SQRFT>
   <Taxes>6000</Taxes>
   <Asking>1,800,000</Asking>
   <Built>July/2019</Built>
   <Listed>07/12/2109</Listed>
   <MSRP>2,000,000</MSRP>
   <Kitchen>5</Kitchen>
   <Baths>2.5</Baths>
   <floors>3</floors>
   <Rooms>5</Rooms>
</config>
</users_provision>

==> cfgYDMWJVLO6YWS.xml <==
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users_provision version="1">
<config version="1">
   <Name>Bobby Marshall</Name>
   <StreeNum>7985</StreeNum>
   <StreetName>E. Beech Road</StreetName>
   <City>Flemington</City>
   <State>NJ</State>
   <ZIP>08822</ZIP>
   <IDcard>YDMWJVLO6YWS</IDcard>
   <URL>msn.com</URL>
   <Dealer>RealtorSales</Dealer>
   <SQRFT>3600</SQRFT>
   <Taxes>6000</Taxes>
   <Asking>1,800,000</Asking>
   <Built>July/2019</Built>
   <Listed>07/12/2109</Listed>
   <MSRP>2,000,000</MSRP>
   <Kitchen>5</Kitchen>
   <Baths>2.5</Baths>
   <floors>3</floors>
   <Rooms>5</Rooms>
</config>
</users_provision>
```

When reading the `.cfg` file I populate/use `tag` and `val` variables the way I do, rather than setting FS to `=` and then using `$1` and `$2` or similar, so that the script will succeed even when any value contains an `=`, e.g. `Dealer=List=>Sold`.

Comment: This too is decent. I didn't miss that awk point it was just getting in my way. In fact I actually had the users file passed before the config file on the input list and thought the way awk processed the files sequentially was giving too much problems.
I like that you built the common parts first then just keep pasting to the output file per user. Could've probably done the same with the head and tail tags.

Comment: wrt `it was just getting in my way` - that's because you misunderstood how to use awk. Yeah, there's various alternatives but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible since you're just learning and there's no clear benefit to building strings from the head and tail text before printing them.